# How to convert an Image to File in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, sharedpreferences

I use sharedpreferences to saved image on user phone, I want to load it as File and not as Image because all my app use image from file so I can't do `imagefile = loadfilefromsharedpreferences()` because one is a File and the other an Image.

I want to change some code to load it as a File but I am stuck.

```
  static Future<String> getImageFromPreferences() async {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return prefs.getString(KEY) ?? null;}

static Image imageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
return Image.memory(
  base64Decode(base64String),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
);}
  static Uint8List dataFromBase64String(String base64String) {
return base64Decode(base64String);}


  static String base64String(Uint8List data) {
return base64Encode(data); }

 loadImageFromPreferences() {getImageFromPreferences().then((img) {
 if (null == img) {
   return;
 }
 setState(() {
   imagefile = imageFromBase64String(img);
 });});}
```